# Remove strings before certain character batch/python

Tags: python

How can I remove letters before certain character? I need to remove every letter from following string until “**[**“ character and redirect output to .csv file.

`{"__metadata": {"uri": loremipsum etc [ {rest of the document}`

Comment: are you sure it's the right solution? is your json file corrupt? if so use `str.partition("[")[0]`

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre OK but how can i implement this to code? I mean I have a variable witch store string and I want to truncate this variable.

Comment: Why did you tag your question with [tag:batch-file]? If you need a batch-file solution: supposing the string is stored in variable `%STRING%`, use `%STRING:*[=[%` returns the first `[` and everything behind...

Comment: @aschipfl but what to do with a file?

Comment: What do you mean? the string is stored in a file, or the result is to be written to a file, or both?

Comment: I have a string in a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your provided info and required fields, i will suggest that if your JSON data is in a file then you can use:

```
import json
data = {}
with open("path to json file") as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
```

or if your data is stored in string then you can simply do

```
data = json.loads("json data string")
```

now you have data in a python dictionary object. now you can easily get any field from the object e.g getting field "cuid" from the first object in entries list:

```
print data["entries"][0]["cuid"]
```

or alternatively you can loop on entries list and get all the fields you need e.g

```
for entry in data["entries"]:
    print entry["cuid"]
    print entry["name"]
    print entry["id"]
    print entry["type"]
```

Comment: but it isn't working when string is stored in variable

Comment: It is working, as you can see I store it in a variable and tested it. From the code in your question, i guess your working on a dict not string , is it like this ?

Comment: yeah you are right, so what I can do? error = 'dict' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: ok, then it depends what you want to extract from the dict. ? is it the value of "uri" your want to extract or something else ?

Comment: share your dict or its structure and let us know what you want to extract out of it, then I can suggest a solution for that.

Comment: `{"__metadata": {"uri": "http://ip:port/vvv/vvv/folders/"}, "first": {"__deferred": {"uri": "http://ip:port/vvv/vvv/folders/?page=1&pagesize=50"}}, "last": {"__deferred": {"uri": "http://ip:port/vvv/vvv/folders/?page=1&pagesize=50"}}, "entries": [{"__metadata": {"uri": "http://ip:port/vvv/vvv/folders/13483"}, `

Comment: `"cuid": "AfbTJW3iTE1MkiLULzA6P58", "name": "foldername1", "description": "", "id": "13483", "type": "Folder", "ownerid": "12", "updated": "Wed Mar 01 09:14:23 CET 2017"}, {"__metadata": {"uri": "http://ip:port/vvv/vvv/folders/523"}, "cuid": "AS1oZEJAynpNjZIaZK2rc7g", "name": "foldername2", "description": "", "id": "523", "type": "Folder", "ownerid": "10", "updated": "Wed Jan 18 00:11:06 CET 2017"},`

Comment: I want to extract all information, but mainly: cuid, name, description, id, type, ownerid, updated.

Comment: I have updated my answer,  I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Unfortunaltely I got this error :json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Comment: This error means that your JSON object is not formatted correctly.  check your JSON structure. try to print you JSON first. if the our is like  u'a' then you need to convert your object to json using json.loads() function.

Comment: why you accepted the answer at first, if you want unaccepted it later on ? its waste of others time.

Answer (score 1):

Find the position of '[' and get the string after that position

```
print s[s.find("[")+1:].strip()
```

Sample output:

```
{rest of the document}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I got invalid syntax error unfortunately.

Comment: There is no syntax error in the answer. Can you share the line that you get the error!?

Comment: `<--the colon` what is that ??

Comment: I guess that we have to extract text from dict

Answer (score 1):

You can split from the first occurence and take the rest like :

```
>>> string = "Egg[spam:miam"
>>> string.split("[", 1)[1]
>>> spam:miam
```

OR

```
>>> string = "Egg[spam:miam"
>>> string[string.index("[") + 1:]
>>> spam:miam
```

Comment: this will throw list index out of range error if the string doesn't have '[' in it!

Comment: @Darkaird but it isn't working when string is stored in variable

Comment: @lukesky what do you mean? It should work whether or not it is stored in a variable.

Comment: @Darkaird AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: and NameError: name 'index' is not defined

Comment: @lukesky I just made mistake "string[index("[") + 1:]" become "string[string.index("[") + 1:]"